# I have waist high boxes but some thing is eating the tops of my beets and beans just the leaves not the stems what could it be?

Tags: vegetables

I have waist high boxes but something is stripping my beet leaves and bean leaves just the very tops leaving the stems—what could it be?

Comment: Deer maybe, depending where you are. But many insect pests and slugs and snails prefer the newer, tender, younger shoots, so that means the tops...

Comment: Did the damage happen over one or two nights, or was this something more gradual?